# Grails searchable plugin search by mapped domain

Tags: grails, query-builder, grails-searchable

we are using grails 2.1.1 and grails searchable-plugin 0.6.4.

We want to search a domain with belongsTo association using searchable.

Suppose we have a domain

```
class A {
  static belongsTo= [b:B]
}
```

Now To Access A with b instance we will write criteria as

```
A.createCriteria.list{
   eq('b',B.get(1))
}
```

Now how to write similar query with searchable Query Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code below (class User has the same relationship as **A** and **B**). I have used this way to change the behavior of the default search:

```
def searchResult = searchableService.search({
  must {
      queryString(params.q)
      must(term('deleted', "false"))
      must(term('status', STATUS_NEW))
      if (loggedUser){
          must(term('User.settings.countryCode', loggedUser.countryCode))
      }
  }
}, params, escape: false, max: 50)
```

Notice that the objects must be marked as **searchable**. Above coding is working fine to me. Please refer to [Searchable Plugin Documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable) for further information.